# Possible issue with grading system on programming Coursera course? Or is it me?

Tags: html, css

I'm currently doing a coursera course called "Introduction to back-end development by Meta" and I have the following issue with this CSS style page (I'm a beginner here). The instructions for the lab assignment are these:

1. Open the `styles.css` file.
2. Add a CSS rule for the `body` element that sets the background color to `#E0E0E2`.
3. Add a CSS rule for the `h1` element that sets the text color to: `#721817`.
4. Add a CSS rule for the `h2` element that sets the text color to: `#721817`.
5. Add a CSS rule for the `center-text` CSS class that aligns the text to `center`.
6. Add a CSS rule for the HTML element with the id `logo`. Set its left and right margins to `auto` and changes its display to a `block` element.
7. Add a CSS rule for all `span` elements that are children of `h2` elements that sets the text color to `#FA9F42` and its font size to `0.75em`.
8. Add a CSS rule for the HTML element with the id `copyright`. Set its top padding to `12` pixels and its font size to `0.75em`.

And this is the code that I have, it seems correct to me, but I haven't checked it with another human, just chatgpt that said everything is correct including the indentation...but I don't really know:

```
body {
    background: #E0E0E2;
}

h1 {
    color: #721817;
}

h2 {
    color: #721817;
}

.center-text {
    text-align: center;
}

#logo {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block;
}

h2 span {
    color: #FA9F42;
    font-size: 0.75em;
}

#copyright {
    padding-top: 12px;
    font-size: 0.75em;
}
```

Now these are the errors that the automatic grading system by Coursera points out:

✗ The 'NEW' labels within  tags should have a color of '#fa9f42' (+ 1 related test)
✗ The element with the ID 'copyright' should have a font-size of 0.75em

I'm 100% sure I did all that, but the implementation might be wrong...or is the Coursera automatic grading is wrong and it's making me fail this assignment? Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: For the New lables issue you can use h2 *{color:#FA9F42;font-size:0.75em} and it will allow css to all tag/text under the h2.

Comment: use the same for #copyright * {css} and you may won't get the error.

Comment: 7. They talk of ‘children’ and you have selected ‘all descendant spans’. Try using >

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I actually changed the h2 element to be:

h2 > * {
    color: #FA9F42;
    font-size: 0.75em;

And submitted that without the rest of the code to see what happens, it obviously gives all kinds of errors because everything else is missing, but it will not actually show an error indicating this, which means this worked.

The problem is when I submit the whole code again, and it again comes up with those two errors again, as if something isn't being implemented correctly and I'm not sure what at this point.